# Nuxt build is too slow on M1 Chip Mac

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js, apple-m1

I'm developing environment for Nuxt project on my new M1 chip Machine(Mac).
The problem is that the Nuxt project's build speed is too slow.

I installed nodenv into my project, and used v12.9.0. In the project folder, used package maneger(npm / yarn) is in `/Users/username/.nodenv/shims/node` .

After I run `yarn install` and `yarn dev`, the compile(Cliend plus Server) takes about 2 hours.

If I run `yarn dev` in my Intel Machine(Mac), the build takes only few seconds.

If you have any ideas for steps to isolate the problem, please teach me.
Thanks,

【My approaches】

- remove `node_modules` and reinstalled them by `yarn install`.
- restart my machine
- simple nuxt project run as the same as on Intel Machine

【environment】

- M1 chip Machine
- nodenv (by homebrew)
- nuxt / vue project

【modules】
my package.json is this,

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/typescript-runtime": "^0.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.9.5",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/google-gtag": "^1.0.4",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.4.0",
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.0.0-0",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/highlight.js": "^9.12.3",
    "@types/quill": "^2.0.3",
    "autolinker": "^3.13.0",
    "blob-util": "^2.0.2",
    "camelcase-keys": "^6.2.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "highlight.js": "^9.18.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "npm-check-updates": "^4.0.6",
    "nuxt": "^2.12.1",
    "nuxt-basic-auth-module": "^1.3.2",
    "nuxt-clipboard2": "^0.2.1",
    "parchment": "^2.0.0-dev.2",
    "pm2": "^4.2.3",
    "quill-image-drop-and-paste": "^1.0.4",
    "sanitize-html": "^1.22.1",
    "snakecase-keys": "^3.1.2",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "^2.4.5",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.4.1",
    "vue-sanitize": "^0.2.0",
    "vue-scrollto": "^2.18.1",
    "vue-stripe-elements-plus": "^0.3.2",
    "vue-toc": "0.0.1",
    "vue-tweet-embed": "^2.4.0",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vuex-persistedstate": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^0.6.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^5.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/moment": "^1.6.0",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.0",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.25.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.25.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^25.2.1",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
    "jest": "^25.2.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.2",
    "prettier": "^2.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "^25.2.1",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.5"
  }
```

Comment: It's possible some modules you are using (or their dependencies) don't have prebuilt M1 binaries (for ones with native code) so it's going through compilation steps.  The package maintainers can upload prebuilt binaries to NPM for some platforms but it will fall back to a build-from-source if they aren't there.  It's hard to say which module(s) are affected without more detail, but it should be easy to tell from the installation log.

Comment: If you've reduced this to a pure nuxt-and-nothing-else codebase (as opposed to nuxt-and-lots-of-other-dependencies-too) and you think it's measuably slower on Apple silicon compared to Intel chips, _talk to the people who make nuxt_ to make them aware of that problem by reporting that behaviour to them over on https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues

Comment: @Joe Thank you. I checked the installation log, but nothing strange was found. I'll check the modules from minor one.(I attached my package.json)

Comment: Don't tell me, tell the folks who make nuxt, so that your report helps improve nuxt _for everyone_ instead of only for folks who find this question on Stackoverflow. You've found a potential problem with an open source project: report that problem to the maintainers of that open source project so that they can fix it. That's part of your responsibility as a user of an open source package.

Comment: So, `yarn dev` is super quick. But `yarn generate` is super slow? Not sure that this is anyhow related to Nuxt by itself. Do you generate some routes or some in your `nuxt.config.js` file? Also, do you have it as a public repo? I could try to run it on my side.

Comment: @kissu Yes, `generate` command takes too much time. 
No, I did not change from initial state in `nuxt.config.js`. 
Yes, this repo(https://github.com/kohey/nuxt-on-m1) takes long time.

Comment: the repo link you have given is a starter/empty project, whilst the package.json above is not, the more code in the project the longer it takes to build

Comment: @LawrenceCherone still, this should not take 2 hours. A M1 chip is often more performant than an i9 Intel, so I doubt there will be a lot of penalty here. More of a configuration/hardware or software configuration issue here.

Comment: @kissu Yes, thanks for you, I could check from other side. I raised your answer +1. Thant you.

Comment: Hi, I cannot see a `+1` on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69065905/8816585).

Answer (score 3):

As expected, there is no actual issue with Nuxt.
`yarn dev` takes 12s and `yarn build` (since `target: server` is the default) takes only around 7s.

You probably have some other issues so far.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by myself.

1. use version node `16.0.0`
2. if using `node-sass`, remove it.
3. instead, install `sass` and `node-loader@7.1.0`
4. `yarn install` & `yarn dev`

This works perfectly for me.

Comment: You were talking about generating the project, not using it in dev so far.